# Google Cloud / GSuite DNS Record or Zone issue

Tags: google-cloud-platform, mx-record, g-suite

To start:

I have read through the Google Cloud DNS documentation.
I have visited the "Creating MX record in Google cloud DNS" on this site.
I believe I may have done something wrong when setting up the DNS Zone, but I am not sure.

The Issue:
I am unable to use my GSuite because it keeps failing on the MX record setup.  I am wondering if the additional period before the domain (when creating a new record) is causing the issue.

[Red cirle around the extra period](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rl5Og.png)

I have configured the nameservers on my hosts site. (Its a GoDaddy Reseller)

[Insanespace Name Servers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fF0m6.png)

Here is my zone.  I'm not sure how helpful it will be.  It was pretty straight forward to setup.

[Google Cloud DNS Zone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lX2lM.png)

I have configured an "@" record but it ends up like this.  I can't seem to figure out how to remove the extra "." that preceeds the domain when adding ANY kind of record.

[MX Record looks like this in Google Cloud DNS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9TVO.png)

Answer (score 1):

Just remove @ symbol from the MX record name - leave it blank.